# How to solve OPENGL Error?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es

I have been getting the following error while executing sample code of EarthquakeCityMap.java. If you need java file then I can share.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Caught RuntimeException: Framebuffer objects are not supported by this hardware (or driver) Read http://wiki.processing.org/w/OpenGL_Issues for help. on thread AWT-EventQueue-1

at javax.media.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:75)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1311)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
at javax.media.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:223)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:525)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:579)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Framebuffer objects are not supported by this hardware (or driver) Read http://wiki.processing.org/w/OpenGL_Issues for help.
at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.init(PJOGL.java:890)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:640)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:662)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$9.run(GLCanvas.java:1366)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1275)
... 28 more

Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Number of texture units not supported by this hardware (or driver)
at processing.opengl.PGL.bindTexture(PGL.java:2646)
at processing.opengl.PGL.createFBOLayer(PGL.java:660)
at processing.opengl.PGL.beginDraw(PGL.java:530)
at processing.opengl.PJOGL.beginDraw(PJOGL.java:617)
at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.beginOnscreenDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:6350)
at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.beginDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1696)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2342)
at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:873)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:672)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1383)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1277)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1131)
at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1394)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone who came across the similar can help me please.

Thanks,

Girish S.

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious enough? Did you try searching for this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

> `Framebuffer objects are not supported by this hardware (or driver)`

You most likely do not have a proper driver installed for your graphics card, or OpenGL is not supported on your card (which is very unlikely, but still possible).